# How to test for more than one conditional?

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean

Suppose I have a variable `y` and a variable `i`.

```
y<- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
i<- 0
```

Let's say I would like to test the following if-statement for **every** boolean condition in `y`:

```
if (y) {
i<-1
}
```

How would I do this? That is, I want `i = 1` if **every** boolean condition in `y` is `TRUE`.

If `y<- c(TRUE, FALSE,TRUE)`, then I want the if-statement to evaluate to `FALSE` and `i=0`. Does anyone know how would I do this? Currently I getting this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (y) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

How would I test the variable `y` for each of it's boolean conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `all` function.

```
> y <- c(T, T, T)
> all(y)
[1] TRUE
> y <- c(T, T, F)
> all(y)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @Dason's answer,  `all()` `any()` `sum()` and `which()` are very useful when working with logical vectors

Example:

```
      vec1 <- c(T, T, F, T, F)

>     all(vec1)   # Are all elements True
      [1] FALSE

>     any(vec1)   # Are any True
      [1] TRUE

>     sum(vec1)   # How many are True
      [1] 3

>     which(vec1) # Which elements (by index) are True
      [1] 1 2 4

>     which(!vec1) # Which elements (by index) are False
      [1] 3 5
```

---

Example 2:

```
vec2 <- c(T, T, T, T, T)

all(vec2)     # TRUE
any(vec2)     # TRUE
sum(vec2)     # 5
which(vec2)   # 1 2 3 4 5
which(!vec2)  # integer(0)
```