# R how many element satisfy a condition?

Tags: r

Is there a better way to count how many elements of a result satisfy a condition?

```
a <- c(1:5, 1:-3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(6:-8)
u <- a > b
length(u[u == TRUE])
## [1] 7
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  [how-to-test-for-more-than-one-conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372158/r-how-to-test-for-more-than-one-conditional/13374197#13374197)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `z` consists of only `TRUE` or `FALSE`, then simply

```
length(which(z))
```

Answer (score 21):

sum does this directly, counting the number of TRUE values in a logical vector:

```
sum(u, na.rm=TRUE)
```

And of course there is no need to construct u for this:

```
sum(a > b, na.rm=TRUE)
```

works just as well.  `sum` will return `NA` by default if any of the values are `NA`.  `na.rm=TRUE` ignores `NA` values in the sum (for logical or numeric).

Comment: And if you use `mean` instead of `sum` then you get the proportion.

Answer (score 8):

I've always used table for this:

```
a <- c(1:5, 1:-3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(6:-8)
table(a>b)
FALSE  TRUE 
    8     7
```