# data.table conditional row count integrated with other non-conditional aggregates in R

Tags: r, count, data.table, conditional-statements, aggregate

Is it possible to include a conditional count with other non-conditional aggregates ? I understand that you can do this with most aggregates functions using which(), but haven't been able to find a solution for counting rows.

For example, the following code sums col1 by col4 into sum1 and sums col2 for which col3 > 3 by col4 into sum2.

```
> DT[, .(sum1 = sum(col1) 
       , sum2 = sum(col2[which(col3 > 3)]))
     , by = (col4)]
```

anything similar for .N? e.g .N[which(col3 > 3)]

I understand you can do this separately using:

```
> DT[col3 > 3, .N, by = .(col4)]  # this works but not what I'm after
```

That's not what I'm after. I'd like to integrate the conditional count with other non-conditional aggregates together if I can using only data.table operations. I wouldn't want using any other packages.

here is sample data:

```
> DT <- data.table(col1 = c(3,5,2,2,4), col2 = c(0,1,0,1,1), col3 = c(3,4,6,7,1), col4 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'a' ,'b'))
> DT
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1:    3    0    3    a
2:    5    1    4    b
3:    2    0    6    a
4:    2    1    7    a
5:    4    1    1    b
```

My desired output:

```
DT[, .( sum1 = sum(col1)
        , sum2 = sum(col3[which(col3 > 3)])
        , count3 = ???????) #.N[which(col3 > 3), but this doesn't work
    , by = .(col4)]

   col4 sum1 sum2 count3
1:    a    7   13      2
2:    b    9    4      1
```

Comment: r u looking for `sum(col3 > 3)`?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your expected output?

Comment: @r2evans I have provided sample data with desired output as requested in edited question. Thanks.

Comment: @chinsoon12 nope. that's not what I am after. I can already do conditional aggregation with sum, as you can see in my sample code of my desired output. What I'm after is conditional count, where you see ??????

Comment: to be more explicit, `DT[, .(sum1 = sum(col1), 
        sum2 = sum(col3[col3 > 3]), 
        count3 = sum(col3 > 3)
    ), by = (col4)]`

Comment: ah! I see what you mean now! yes yes, of course that works! thanks! could you please put it as the solution so i can mark it?

Comment: highly likely a dupe

Comment: yes, very likely! my search didn't result in any solution though. this was an obvious solution too! slow brain today. thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R how many element satisfy a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907320/r-how-many-element-satisfy-a-condition)